# Man pages no Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, linha-de-comando

no terminal de comandos do Linux podemos acessar as páginas de manual das aplicações. Tipo man date.

Existe algo equivalente no cmd do Windows? Por exemplo, eu queria saber detalhes do comando tasklist (suas variações e tal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `/?` depois do comando.

```
tasklist /?
```

Comment: A resposta te ajudou? Se sim aceita ela.

Comment: Isso aí! Valeu!